# Selenium IDE popup window

Tags: selenium-ide

im new to selenium ide. i need to automate the testing of an export function which i am unable to automate.

1. Click Export and Window will pop up (done)
2. Select the Save File radio button which is the 2nd option. (only able select window)
3. It will prompt the directory which i will save
4. Press Ok button

[Click here for image of Popup Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD6Nt.jpg)

My Codes

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=reportExport</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForPopUp</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>30000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>selectWindow</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Selenium IDE cannot handle download confirmation dialogs. So it is impossible to press the **OK** button. But you can still test the export function by bypassing the download confirmation dialog to automatically download the file.
The steps are found [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file).

Although in my opinion as well as [this](http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/) article, it is not a very good idea to automate file downloading.